# Is it possible to have two WCF service share a relying party trust in ADFS?

Tags: c#, wcf, adfs, channelfactory

We have a bunch of services using claims base authentication, that each have their own relying party trust in ADFS 2.1. I'm investigating if we can reduce the chatter between clients and ADFS by having multiple services use the same RP trust in ADFS. This would allow a client to call any of these services with the same security token.

However, I can't find how to explicitly specify the relying party id when using the ChannelFactory class. I assume WCF is using the endpoint address in the RST (Issue) call to ADFS.

Is it possible to do this? If so, how would this be coded?

When I currently try to call the service, I get this error:

```
Microsoft.IdentityServer.Framework.SecurityTokenService.FailedAuthenticationException:
MSIS3055: The requested relying party trust '<service address>' is unspecified or
unsupported. If a relying party trust was specified, it is possible the user does not
have permission to access the relying party trust. --->
Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.Policy.PolicyServer.Engine .ScopeNotFoundPolicyRequestException: 
MSIS3020: The relying party trust with identifier '<service address>' could not be
located.
```

Comment: Set up a custom relying sts that doesn't require configuring relying parties (like adfs does). Register it once in the adfs. Then use it as sts for all your web services.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That may work but would make the security configuration even more complex. I was looking for a way to do this with ADFS itself.

Comment: No problem, if you find one, let me know ;)